# How to add input width on .animate

Tags: jquery, set, jquery-animate, width

I want to set width auto on `.animate({width: "auto"}, 'slow');`, but this is not working?
If someone can help I'll really appreciate.

**fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/327/

Thank you !

Comment: When you say auto, do you mean that you want the width to adjust to the text inside?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Added  a dynamic element (button) on blur to calculate the width and removed right away.. So you don't need to change anything in html.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/333/)

```
var $getWidth = $('#getTextWidth');

$('input[type=text]')
.focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length > 22) {
        //$(this).data('default', $(this).data('default') || $(this).width());
        $this.stop().animate({width: 370}, 'slow');
        $this.parent().addClass('cooling');
    }
})
.blur(function() { /* lookup the original width */
    var $this = $(this);

    var textWidth = $('<input type="button" />')
        .appendTo('body')
        .attr({'id': 'tmpSpan'})
        .css({display: 'none'})
        .val($this.val()).outerWidth();
    $('#tmpSpan').remove();
    $this.stop().animate({width: textWidth + 'px'},'fast');
    $this.parent().removeClass('cooling');
});
```

I added a hidden span, and then added the textbox content inside the span to calculate the width of the span. Then got the outerWidth of the span and applied it to textbox on blur.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/332/)

Comment: Thank you SKS but is not working very well :( and I cannot add a span in my html because I've got a lot of html pages in my app and if I modify in all pages ... will take a long time. I'll give you a vot but not the best answer .

Comment: @mcmwhfy Check out my new demo.. no html changes.

Answer (score 2):

This works and its simple [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/E2KFS/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[type=text]").focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "160px"
    }, 100);
});
$(this).focusout(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").animate({
        width: "130px"
    }, 100);
});});
```